# Basic dynamic memory allocation and delete triggers an asssertion failed

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

I am doing some reviewing of the basics of C++, and I have some troubles understanding why my code is triggering an assertion failed.

```
void fonctionPointeur(int a)
{
    int* p = new int;
    p = &a; 
    std::cout << p << "----" << *p << std::endl;    
    delete p;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    int a = 6;
    fonctionPointeur(a);
}
```

The assertion failed that I'm triggering is always different, which leads me to think that the delete of `p` is accessing some unknown memory slot.
When I remove the `delete p;` or the `p = &a;` then everything work just fine.

It seems to me that I'm not supposed to delete `p` and that it will be delete at the end of the scope, but it's dynamic allocation it's not supposed to be the case...

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Ask yourself: What does `p = &a;` do to the pointer?  Does it still point to the same memory you created with new?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! I write int *p = new int(6); instead this way the memory owner is only the pointer p and he is free to delete it has he please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression

```
int* p = new int;
```

you are assigning to `p` a memory block allocated by `new`.

In this expression

```
p = &a;
```

you are assigning to `p` the address of mere temporary, a copy of the original variable `a` (as you pass it by copy in `fonctionPointeur`), that temporary cannot be `delete`d.

This is to be specific, even if you passed it by reference (`void fonctionPointeur(int &a)`) the problem remains, you also can't `delete` it as wasn't dynamically allocated.

Moreover, because `p` is now pointing to `a`, you lost access to the memory previously allocated, you cannot `delete` it anymore, this is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that I'm not supposed to delete p

This is either correct or not correct depending on which value you are referring to:

> ```
> int* p = new int;
> ```

This is the first value that you give for `p`. You must delete the result of `new int` or else the memory leaks.

> ```
> p = &a;
> ```

Here, you assign a new value for `p`, overwriting the old value. You must not delete the result of `&a` because it is a pointer to an object with automatic storage. If you do delete this, then behaviour of the program is undefined.

You must have deleted `p` before overwriting the value because the previous value will be lost. Otherwise since this is the only copy of the pointer, this overwriting of the value guarantees a memory leak.

> and that it will be delete at the end of the scope,

`a` which `p` points to will be destroyed automatically and its automatic storage will be deallocated.

The dynamic object which `p` used to point to will not be destroyed automatically and its dynamic storage will not be deallocated.

---

P.S. It his hardly ever useful to dynamically allocate an `int`. I recommend avoiding unnecessary dynamic allocation.

P.P.S I recommend avoiding owning bare pointers.